# What does "-10 User was removed" mean?

Tags: support, voting, user-accounts

I noticed this in my "activity drop down:"

[image: user removed]

I don't particular care about losing 10 points, but it piqued my interest. What does this mean? If someone's account is deleted for some reason, their up votes are taken away?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the user who upvoted your post got removed from the system, his votes are deleted as well.

- [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

Comment: This of course reminds me that I should have searched over at meta.stackoverflow.com first. Most of these network wide questions have usually been asked there before.